# mkdir system call creates permissions 0755 instead of 0777

Tags: c++, bash, c++11, unix, permissions

I have an issue with the permissions I get when I use the mkdir system call. I know for a fact I'm calling it right, it's in octal, all that. I've tested it where the mode input is an integer that I can do math with and definitely is 511 in decimal.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    if (mkdir(argv[argc-1], 0777) == -1) {
        perror(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } // if         
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // main
```

But when I create a directory and check the permissions, it's always 0755 instead of 0777.

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)
```

When I use the mkdir utility or chmod or whatever it can set to 0777 perfectly. It's just the system call that's not working.

It also works fine for *lesser* permissions, like if I set the mode to 0111.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your umask is 0022?

Check it with

```
$ umask
```

from your shell.

In this case, set to zero the umask with

```
$ umask 0
```

and try again with your program

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Comment: @Reed - not at all.